# Excel Create Date and Hour Series

Tags: excel, date, time, series

I would like to create in Excel in a column, e.g A, date and time series with a certain time step. For example:

```
14.10.2016 00:00:00
14.10.2016 04:00:00
14.10.2016 08:00:00
```

and so on.....

Then just drag the cell down and go as further in date as I want.

Any idea? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill the first two cells with the initial value and the step value for example:

A1 = 14.10.2016 00:00:00

A2 = 14.10.2016 04:00:00

Now highlight both cells and drag down from the bottom right corner of the second cell

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately doesnt work. if i did that, then the next cell will be 14.10.2016 00:00:01 the next 14.10.2016 04:00:01 etc

Comment: I think you are not doing it the way I'm trying to explain, I could show you if you have a team viewer or something

Comment: Ok you are right, you need to setup the right formating, so this trick to work

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have teamviewer, Anyway I think I am doing it exactly the way you describe it. So there must be sth else which causes the problem, since it works in your excel file.

Comment: Try to setup the format for the date because I did it with                    01/02/2016  11:00:00      **                                                               01/02/2016  11:04:00       **                                                                01/02/2016 11:08:00  this format

Comment: yes now it is working! thanks a lot mate help! appreciated!

Comment: @MGs If this solution solved your problem then please [mark this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as the accepted answer (and possibly up-vote it). This will show to other users on this site, that this question has been solved and doesn't require their attention anymore. Also, if someone is looking for a solution to a particular problem then this post will show up as a question with a working solution (since it has been solved). Most importantly, this shows your appreciation for the help got and is the generally accepted mean of saying "thank you" on this site.

Comment: Didn't work for me!
I want to generate hourly dates and the Excel suddenly changes minutes or the seconds.